# STS randomly crashes on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ram, spring-tool-suite

Two months i experience crashing STS (3.7.3.RELEASE) on ubutnu 14.04.

Before posting this, i made following steps:

1. Reinstalled STS
2. Reinstalled java-oracle (web8upd ppa)
3. Changing workspace also made no difference

The issue randomly appears after clicking on Server Tab (doesnt matter on server or not) and then it closes without any warning.

The log file is huge, i leave link: http://pastebin.com/zFLQWf7u

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: You could try to set SWT_GTK3=0 before you startup Eclipse/STS in order to switch the GTK version that is being used by STS back to GTK2. I am not sure if that is related to the issue in the end, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me that we might be able to fix. There an action in tc server integration plugin that requires java.awt.Desktop to navigate to URL. Judging from your stack trace java.awt.Desktop seem to be problematic on Ubuntu. Perhaps we can rework the navigation to URL using Eclipse's utilities to navigate to URL.
Please raise an issue here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS SERVER component, put a link to your stack trace and we'll try to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by it happens on eclipse too? :-) Did you install tc server plugin into plain Eclipse? Or you really mean plain eclipse without any STS related plugins? If no tc server plugin installed what do you click to get a JVM crash?

Comment: Hello, i tested on 3 different conditions/enviroments: 1) Eclipse(pure), 2)Eclipse with STS plugin(downloaded from Market) 3) The "original" STS (since it's based on Eclipse - correct me if i'm wrong)
Overall, i experience less jvm crashes on pure Eclipse environment and Eclipse + STS plugin. After @Martin Lippert suggested to use `export SWT_GTK3=0` before launching  STS - it made profit for me. however i experience freezing on startup now (i guess it's cpu overcloak)

Comment: Just curious, what are the errors in the thread dump/log when JVM crashes on pure Eclipse without any STS plugins?

Comment: Same log goes. Since last conversation, i switched cpu core power consumption from "Dynamic Switching" to "Low power consumption" and i experience no crashes so far on STS... it's really weird.

Comment: The log for JVM crashes in STS had tc server plugin class involved, but there is no tc server plugin on plain eclipse so log must be somewhat different. I'm curious what is it in plain Eclipse that makes JVM crashing vs eclipse + tc server plugin.