# Eclipse is crashing 30 times a day

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse disappears withing 5-10 minutes of being started.  This just started happening in the last 5 days or so.  I've tried to ensure everything is at the latest release.  At this point eclipse is nearly unusable.  Any help  will be greatly appreciated.  The stack trace from the log is below.

```
!SESSION 2016-11-28 11:54:36.680 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product

This is a continuation of log file /home/ses44/workspace/.metadata/.bak_8.log
Created Time: 2016-11-28 11:55:30.418

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core 4 2 2016-11-28 11:55:30.418
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.util.VirtualReferenceUtilities.getDefaultProjectArchiveName(VirtualReferenceUtilities.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getJavaClasspathReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getNonManifestRefs(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.util.FacetModuleCoreSupportDelegate.getReferenced(FacetModuleCoreSupportDelegate.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.util.FacetModuleCoreSupport.getReferenced(FacetModuleCoreSupport.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.taglib.TaglibIndex.internalGetAvailableTaglibRecords(TaglibIndex.java:859)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.taglib.TaglibIndex.getAvailableTaglibRecords(TaglibIndex.java:495)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.metadata.internal.TaglibMetaDataLocator.locateMetaDataModelProviders(TaglibMetaDataLocator.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.DomainLoadingStrategy.locateMetaDataSourceInstances(DomainLoadingStrategy.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.DomainLoadingStrategy.load(DomainLoadingStrategy.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModel.load(MetaDataModel.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModelManager.loadMetadata(MetaDataModelManager.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModelManager.getModel(MetaDataModelManager.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.internal.MetaDataQueryHelper.getMDModel(MetaDataQueryHelper.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.internal.MetaDataQueryHelper.getModel(MetaDataQueryHelper.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.internal.MetaDataQueryHelper.getEntities(MetaDataQueryHelper.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.internal.MetaDataQueryHelper.getEntity(MetaDataQueryHelper.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.metadataprocessors.MetaDataEnabledProcessingFactory.getAttributeValueRuntimeTypeFeatureProcessors(MetaDataEnabledProcessingFactory.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.metadataprocessors.MetaDataEnabledProcessingFactory.getAttributeValueRuntimeTypeFeatureProcessors(MetaDataEnabledProcessingFactory.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy.validateNonELAttributeValue(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:695)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy.access$1(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy$1.run(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy.validateAttributeValue(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy.validate(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.XMLViewDefnValidator.validateTag(XMLViewDefnValidator.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.XMLViewDefnValidator.validateRegions(XMLViewDefnValidator.java:177)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.XMLViewDefnValidator.validateView(XMLViewDefnValidator.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.ui.internal.validation.DefaultFaceletValidationStrategy.doValidate(DefaultFaceletValidationStrategy.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.ui.internal.validation.AbstractFaceletValidationStrategy.validateFile(AbstractFaceletValidationStrategy.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.ui.internal.validation.HTMLValidator.validate(HTMLValidator.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.Validator$V2.validate(Validator.java:1159)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.validate(ValManager.java:704)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager$1.visit(ValManager.java:665)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.accept(ValManager.java:810)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.validate(ValManager.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob$Visitor.visit(ValBuilderJob.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$2.visit(Resource.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$1.visitElement(Resource.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.fullBuild(ValBuilderJob.java:219)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.run(ValBuilderJob.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.runInWorkspace(ValBuilderJob.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Do you need the J2EE components?

Comment: What do you mean by "disappears"? Does it just vanish? What OS are you using?

Comment: Reinstall eclipse. Your projects are stored separately, so with a fresh install you should just need to tell it where your workspace is, and it'll pick everything back up.

Comment: @dcsohl  I reinstalled yesterday.  Same result.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I need JEE components

Comment: Not a first time i see someone who suffers from 'eclipse on linux' problem. May i ask you, what OS distribution do you use and did you installed java via web8team ppa?

Comment: @tddmonkey - It completely disappears and requires a restart.  The only clue I have is the stack dump listed

Comment: @Reborn - I'm running Xubuntu 16.04.   Kernel 4.8.0-27.

Comment: @ussmith well then, this issue persisted on 14.04. try the suggestion from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557102/sts-randomly-crashes-on-ubuntu from STS lead dev. hope it helps. It differs from mines a bit, but it has common things.

Comment: That looks like a bug, specifically where it's making an invalid assumption about one of your other Java Projects. It wouldn't cause a complete meltdown, though. Perhaps the culprit is in `/home/ses44/workspace/.metadata/.bak_8.log`?

Comment: I would take a look at the OOM killer

Comment: From where did you get Eclipse? From the linux repo or from www.eclipse.org?

Comment: @E-Riz from the eclipse site.  It's the BIRT (reporting) package.

Comment: @tddmonkey - It's a problem with the JSF validator.  I've been able to trace it to when eclipse is scanning the JSF files in my project space.

Comment: Have you tried disabling JSF validation for the project?

Comment: @E-Riz I turned off JSF Application Configuration Validator and the JSF View Validator.  Those are the only ones that jump out in the validation configuration.